# Downloading Oracle Kodo for using with WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm developing a Java EE web application on WebLogic Workshop 10.3.

I'm trying to add facets of JPA(1.0) and Oracle Kodo(4.1). I tried to add the Kodo library from the Oracle site. (Selected Option, Use Oracle Kodo library from Oracle web site).

I get the following exception:

```
Failed while downloading Oracle Kodo library from Oracle site.

sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm not able to see which URL workshop is trying to connect to.

Is there any free download of the KODO library? I had tried to download it in the past and I was able to download it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be useful for you, but I work with WebLogic Server 12c and it has build in support for Toplink and Kodo (default JPA provider can be changed [using console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/taskhelp/domainconfig/ConfigureDefaultJPAProvider.html)). So if WebLogic Server 10.3 has same settings for default JPA provider, then you should have Kodo somewhere in Middleware direcotory (`modules` subdirecotry, I suppose). I have WebLogic Server 10.3.3 installed where `Middleware10.3.3\modules\com.bea.core.kodo_1.2.0.0_4-2-1.jar` jar situated. Is it what you need?

Comment: +1 I have WebLogic 10.3.0 here and the Kodo libraries are also there, same folder.